# Ionic cordova plugin build windows does not work with CLI

Tags: angularjs, cordova, msbuild, ionic2

I build a new Ionic app and install Cordova with its plugin. Angular work fine and shows in browser properly using CLI.

Visual studio code for editing and processing and running in Windows 10.

I add windows platform using CLI and works properly but when I build. I got this error.

> MSBuild v4.0 is not supported, aborting.
>           Error: AppPackages doesn't exists

How can I run the code on Windows platform?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This problem is because there is no Visual Studio installed 2015 and later.

At the same machine should install:

1. Microsoft SDK latest version.
2. Visual studio with enabling cross platform feature during the installation selection.

Then, you can run the commands ionic **build** and **run** from

> Developer Command Prompt VS 2017